# soapClient method __soapCall automatically applies encoding, the service doesn't want encoded data, any solution or custom implementation?

Tags: php, encoding

I have my own implementation of soap-client class, my `createRecord` method is:

```
public function createRecord($username, $password, $doctypeName, $parentDoctypeName, $sXmlAttributes, $attachment, $fileName)
  {
    return $this->__soapCall('createRecord', array($username, $password, $doctypeName, $parentDoctypeName, $sXmlAttributes, $attachment, $fileName));
  }
```

`$sXmlAttributes` contains XML encapsulated in CDATA, HTML entity encoding is being automatically applied to this parameter, i want to avoid HTML entity encoding as this parameter contains XML, Can anyone help me in sending this request without applying HTML entity encoding to `sXmlAttributes` parameter whose value i.e. is already encapsulated in CDATA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass an xml document node as a function parameter, your need to create a SoapVar object with a text represention of the xml node and the XSD_ANYXML encoding constant. However, this constant is not exported by the extension and is not documented for some unknown reason.

Therefore, to get this to work you must either register the XSD_ANYXML #define as a PHP constant, or use the integer value of the constant when creating the SoapVar, which is 147.

```
$soapvar = new SoapVar($xml_text, 147);

$params = array("ItemXml" => $soapvar, "PropertyView" => "blah");
$result = $this->soapclient->__soapCall("SaveItem", array("parameters"=>$params), null, $this->soapheaders);
```

However, this still doesnt give the correct result. For some reason, the ItemXml parameter node is not wrapped around the associated xml parameter in the soap request, and the following soap is produced (assumming 'blah' is used as the $xml_text):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="..." xmlns:ns1="...">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>...</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:SaveItem>
<item>blah</item>
<ns1:PropertyView>blah</ns1:PropertyView>
</ns1:SaveItem>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Anoher example, if the function (called myFunc) expect a parameter called xmlInput you should do something like this:

```
$soapvar = new SoapVar($query, XSD_STRING);
$result = $client->myFunc(array('xmlInput'=>$soapvar));
```

In this example, when defining variable soapVar I assigned the type XSD_STRING rather than as XSD_ANYXML.
And when calls to the function you must pass the soapVar in an associative array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I agree to you Sajid, the above solution works using XSD_ANYXML constant for me. I modified code as

public function createRecord($username, $password, $doctypeName, $parentDoctypeName, $sXmlAttributes, $attachment, $fileName)
  {
    $soapvar = new SoapVar($sXmlAttributes, XSD_ANYXML);
    $resp = $this->_*soapCall('createRecord', array($username, $password, $doctypeName, $parentDoctypeName, $soapvar, $attachment, $fileName));
    echo "===================================----";
    echo $this->*_getLastRequest();
    echo "===================================----";
    return $resp;
  }

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving this answer because it might help others, as @SajidAli's answer didn't fix 100% for me.

When using `XSD_STRING` it wouldn't work because the content got encoded.
Using `XSD_ANYXML` doesn't encode but for some reason doesn't create a new node, and this is bad for me cause I need it inside a node with somename.

What really worked was use `XSD_ANYXML` and hardcode the tag node inside SoapVar, like this:

```php
$wholeTag = new SoapVar("<anytag><![CDATA[{$xmlContent}]]></anytag>", XSD_ANYXML);
$data = [
  'prop1' => 'value1',
  'prop2' => 'value2',
  'prop3' => $wholeTag,
];

$soapClient->__soapCall('method_name', $data);
```